# Physics problems in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I have a problem with the physics of my game. I created a wall formed by rigidbodies (simple cubes 1 * 1) of a single layer. At first, it remained perfectly still if it did not apply any force. However, the next day, this wall wobbles as if the rigidbodies were not properly placed, or as if an external force affected them. I've tried other scenes and projects, but the same thing happens. Even creating only a tower of 1 * 1 straight cubes also wobbles. I do not know what to change about the physical settings of the project, I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Because of unavoidable floating point rounding problems, colliders that are overlapping or even 'exactly' touching may try to get away from each other when the scene is loaded, which can cause wobbling.  If you shrink them all a little bit so they aren't touching, that could help, but can also cause wobbling.

What I try to do is, I freeze the objects positions until physics is really needed.  Then when a ball hits the wall, I'd unfreeze the positions of objects in a certain radius from the ball so they can collapse with physics.  If you want a chain reaction, then you can also have cubes tell cubes next to them that they moved, so maybe the neighbors should unfreeze now too.

Comment: yeah, i was thinking in something like that, activate or deactivate the rigidbody component, but i was strange beacause in the beggining it works well. Thanks for your answer!!